# Debug different projects using sources instead of m2 in intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have 2 projects (A & B) consisting of multiple modules which interact among each other. Let's say I debug a module of project A which at a later stage jumps into a module of project B. Intellij in this case uses a decompiled source code from the jar inside .m2 repo instead of the source files.

A possible workaround is to specifiy the sources when intellij shows the decompiled version but that is really tedious for multiple classes and modules.

How do I tell Intellij to use the sources?

Additional infos: Project A and B are in two separate folders and I have loaded Project A using its pom.xml. I manually use cmd to call 'mvn clean install'. Essentially, I need to specify an additional classpath to search for sources. At the moment the debug config is set to search the whole project but as project B is in another folder this is not possible.

I am not allowed to do changes to the pom.xml files inside each project and modules. I would also prefer to have both projects in separate folders.